# ValueError: math domain error . why i got this error

Tags: python

This Function was Working but i modified something in project then i got math domain error and i didn't change anything on it

```
def entropy(self,num,total):
    num2=total-num
    if num/total == 0 :
        return 0
    elif num2/total == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        entropoy_value=(-num/total*math.log(num/total,2)+(-num2/total*math.log(num2/total,2)))
        return entropoy_value
```

Comment: You'll need to tell us what you "modified in project"

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have negative value in `num` or `total`, which will lead to domain error: `math.log(x)` if x<=0.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to take the log of a negative number (ie num2 is negative)